# Find latest matching entry from log file

Tags: powershell-2.0, select-string

I have a log file, which is being written to constantly throughout the day. 
I need a way to check the logfile, and find the last entry that matches a specific string.

This entry could be 5 rows from the end or 5000 rows.

I'm reluctant to read the whole log (which by the end of the day could be in excess of 60000 lines).

I also don't really want to pull out all entries that match and then get the last one, as when things are running, the matching entries could make up as much as as a third of the log.

So far everything I can find is either about using `Select-String` to get all matches into an array, and then get the last one, or using `(Get-Content xxx) [-1..-x]` to get the last x rows. Neither of which really does what I need.

The closest I have managed thus far is:

```psh
$fullResult = (Get-Content $location)[-1 .. -5000] | 
                    Select-String -Pattern $srch -List |
                    Select-Object -First 1
```

But this isn't perfect as it only reads the last 5000 lines, if the result I am after is on line 5001 it will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything wrong with simply using a `Where-Object` filter?

```psh
Get-Content $location |
  Where-Object { $_ -match $srch } |
  Select-Object -Last 1
```

Comment: cheers, in principle it works, but it still seems to read from the top down, as when I run it against a full days logfile it takes quite a while to run if the result it needs is at the very end.

Comment: @IGGt You can't skip if you can't define where to stop.

Comment: fair enough I suppose. I just thought that maybe there would be a way to start reading at the end, as I would imagine for most people, the most important information is usually at the end of a logfile, rather than the start.

Comment: @IGGt Computers don't work that way under the hood (because of the way traditional storage media work). To read a file backwards they have to either read the entire file into an array and traverse that in reverse order, or read the file multiple times, reducing the number of skipped bytes with every iteration.